# Subquery is returning more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT  
    dbo.Customers.Company, 
    MAX(dbo.Orders.ShipDate) AS Expr1,
    (SELECT dbo.OrderItems.Price FROM dbo.OrderItems) AS Expr2
FROM 
    dbo.Customers
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Orders ON dbo.Customers.CustomerID = dbo.Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.OrderItems ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.OrderItems.OrderID
WHERE 
    (dbo.Orders.Deleted = 0)
GROUP BY 
    dbo.OrderItems.InvMasID, dbo.Customers.Company
```

I am trying to pull the price from `dbo.OrderItems.Price` that is associated with the correlating `dbo.Orders.ShipDate` that is called in the outer query. My query keeps throwing an error saying that the inner query is returning more than 1 value.

My question is how would I go about having the inner query pull only the values matching the what the outer query is pulling.

Comment: Why do you use `(SELECT dbo.OrderItems.Price FROM dbo.OrderItems)` instead of simply `OrderItems.Price`? You do join `dbo.OrderItems`.

Comment: You should post also the structure of your tables, if you want that we help you

Comment: Your subquery, "SELECT dbo.OrderItems.Price FROM dbo.OrderItems," is returning all rows in your OrderItems table as you have not restricted it in any way. You need to add a WHERE clause to restrict its resultset to a single record that is tied to the current row processed from dbo.Customers. I would look into using OUTER APPLY rather than you subquery as it is faster and less expensive. Also, dbo.OrderItems.Price is unnecessary. In this scenario, you can get away with simply using Price.

Comment: Remove "top 100 percent" and forget it exists. It does nothing useful. If you are using that because you are trying to define a view, then there are 2 lessons to learn. First is that a resultset has no defined order unless the query that generates it includes an order by clause. This holds regardless of the source of the rows (table, function, view, etc.) And again, the optimizer knows "100 percent" is a meaningless expression and ignores it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Subquery Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017310/select-subquery-group-by)

Comment: Basically I can pull the max date which shows the last time a customer purchased a product. I am looking to also pull the price associated with that date and customer so max(price) would not work as it pulls the highest price in the table. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explain which customer order you want, and whether you want the whole order price or the price of each item in that order, we can be more specific. I had to make some assumptions (see comments):

```
select
      c.Company
    , o.ShipDate as this_is_max_ship_date_of_customer 
    , o.OrderID --Added OrderID so you know what the price is associated with
    , sum(oi.price) this_is_sum_of_prices_of_the_order
                --if you want the price of a particular item, you can add ItemID beneath OrderID and also group by it
from dbo.Customers c
join dbo.Orders o
    on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
join dbo.OrderItems oi
    on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
where o.Deleted = 0
    and o.ShipDate in (select max(inner_o.ShipDate) from dbo.Orders inner_o
                       where inner_o.Company = c.Company
                       group by inner_o.Company)
                       --This subquery points to the outer reference - a useful trick
                       -- it means only the most recent ShipDate for the customer is shown
    and o.OrderId in (select max(inner_o2.OrderId) from dbo.Orders inner_o2
                       where inner_o2.Company = c.Company
                         and inner_o2.ShipDate = o.ShipDate
                       group by inner_o2.Company)
                       --This subquery is doing the same thing, but for your OrderId
                       --Unfortunately you don't specify enough in your question, so
                       --  I have to assume you only want their most recent order
                       --To prevent an ShipDate that is not of the OrderId you care about,
                       --  I had to add the second where clause here
group by
    c.Company,
    o.ShipDate,
    o.OrderId
```

Comment: Notice how both answers are adding letters after the table names.  This is called aliasing.  You can give your tables a shorter name so you don't type them all out, then type that alias followed by a period then the column you're wanting.  Also, when you group by 'InvMasID' this is going to change the behavior of the query.  What is this?

Comment: Also, "INNER JOIN' for 'modern' versions of SQL SERVER can now just be 'JOIN'

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide how you want to combine all the different prices on the orders for a company.  I don't know what you want.  For instance, the following returns the sum of all the prices:

```
SELECT c.Company, MAX(o.ShipDate) AS Latest_ShipDate,
       SUM(oi.Price) AS sum_Price
FROM dbo.Customers c JOIN
     dbo.Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID JOIN
     dbo.OrderItems oi
    ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
WHERE o.Deleted = 0
GROUP BY oi.InvMasID, c.Company
```

Comment: OP should offer an explanation of the InvMasID.  I suspect it's specific to an item parameter which will cause this query to produce some unexpected results.